# Problems with creating large MultiIndex (10 million rows) in Python Pandas used to reindex large DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

My situation is I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex including a `TimeStamp` and number (wavelength from 280-4000 nm) where the wavelength number spacing changes from every 1 nm to 5 nm. I need 1 nm spacing and plan to and plan to linearly interpolate after reindexing my DataFrame.

I tried to create a `MultiIndex` using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()` and providing two lists of about 4000 items in length each which resulted in Python using up all my computer's RAM. The code looks like:

```
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([times_list, waves_list],
                        names=['TmStamp', 'Wvlgth']
                                   )
```

`from_product()` is a simple function so I don't think I'm messing it up but I would think it would be able to handle even larger lists than I've passed it.

To try to get around this I've used `pd.MultiIndex()` and passed the unique levels, indentical to what I passed with `.from_product()` but constructed the labels for each using the code below:

```
times = Series(df.index.get_level_values('TmStamp').values).unique()
times_Series = Series(times)
times_label_list = list()
counter = 0
for i in times_Series:
    temp_list = Series([counter] * 3721)
    times_label_list.append(temp_list)
    counter +=1 
times_label = pd.concat(times_label_list)
```

and

```
waves_levels = np.arange(280,4001,1).tolist()
waves_label = np.arange(0,3721,1).tolist() * times_count
```

which are used in

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex([times_list, waves_levels],
                  labels=[times_label, waves_label],
                  names=['TmStamp','Wvlng']
                 )
```

and the `MultiIndex` is used to reindex my df

```
ri_df = df.reindex(midx)
```

My questions are:

- Am I messing up `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()` or can it not handle being passed large lists?
- Is my workaround valid or am I falling into any pitfalls?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show what the times_label/list objects are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem. You need to be more specific on what the times_list actually are.

```
In [2]: mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range('20130101',freq='s',periods=4000),
   ...:                                  np.arange(280,4000)],names=['times','wl'])

In [4]: mi.nbytes/(1024*1024.0)
Out[4]: 56.82167148590088

In [6]: len(mi)
Out[6]: 14880000
```

Comment: Being specific looks like it worked! The solution is actually in my proposed work around and used: `Series(df.index.get_level_values('TmStamp').values).unique()` rather than just `df.index.get_level_values('TmStamp')`. Thinking about it more there was probably an issue because the original `df.index` had over 4 million instances with thousands of duplicates. Having 3 orders of magnitude more than expected is what probably led to overuse of my RAM and would have led to an undesired result anyway. Thanks Jeff!